# Задача на двумерные массивы.Циклический сдвиг

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Произвести циклический сдвиг столбцов квадратной матрицы `A[N]` на `K` позиций вправо.

Входные данные:
Одно натуральное число `N`. Далее с новой строки `N` строк по `N` целых чисел в каждой. `N` не превышают десяти. Затем с новой строки записано натуральное число `K`.

Выходные данные:
Вывести на исходную матрицу `N` на `N`, столбцы которой циклически сдвинуты на `K` позиций вправо. Числа разделять пробелами.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int arr[n][n];    
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {               
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {            
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);            
        }
    }    

    int shift;
    scanf("%d", &shift);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
        int temp_0 = arr[i][0], temp_1 = 0;
        for(int j = 0, k = 0; k < n; k++) {              
            temp_1 = arr[i][(j + shift) % n];
            arr[i][(j + shift) % n] = temp_0;
            j = (j + shift) % n;            
            temp_0 = temp_1;
        }        
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {               
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {            
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 

  return 0;
}
```

К массивам перешёл недавно. Необходимо указать на мои ошибки в данном
решении(программа работает некорректно для некоторых массивов) или привести другое решение с учётом имеющих у меня знаний; а именно - массивы, циклы, ветвление.

В решение можно сам массив не изменять а просто вывести его со смещением.

Comment: Для отладки достаточно одномерного массива. Какая логика используется при проведении обменов?

Comment: Член массива который я смещаю будет занимать кокое-то положение.Я нахожу это положение значение этого члена сохраняю в temp_1 а на место этого элемента сохраняю ранее сохранённый элемент предыдущего смещения который по существу смещаемый член, следующий проход цикла я должен продолжать с того места в которое я сделал смещение далее  сущетвующее сохранённое значение я зделаю как бы предыдущим. Число таких операция равно числу элементов в строке. Первый элемен в таков в случает является конечныв в цикле , как бы скачет по мосиву на длинну сещения к примеру 5 членов строки 0-3-1-4-2-0.

Comment: А если вернулись на то же место, а всё не обошли? Такое случится, если длина строки и сдвиг не взаимно простые числа (например, n=6, shift = 2)

Comment: Так не получится - вернее, получится *в редких случаях* взаимно простых чисел... Если хотите сохранять в массиве - см. мой ответ. Впрочем, в нем приведен и тривиальный вариант, когда сохранять ничего не нужно.

Comment: @Harry: **Так** все прекрасно получится, просто все это надо делать правильно, т.е. помня о том, что перестановка может распасться не на один, а не несколько циклов. Не надо, пожалуйста, на SO спешить с ответами в стиле "выкинь все свое нафиг и делай как я".

Comment: @MBo: Тема такая двумерные масивы на курсе. Чтобы понять что лучше, надо попробывать всё что только можно.

Comment: Автор, обратите также внимание на метод с 3 reverse, описанный в ответе @Harry (он достаточно эффективен и его очень просто запомнить (а это неубиваемый плюс))

Comment: @avp Может я нестандартно начал свой путь, начав изучать первым язык, нежеле сначала изучить базовые алгоритмы. Многие пишут что необходимо начать именно с алгоритмитизации, но для меня лично , мой  подход является иффективным. Может от по времени и дольше , но таким образом я действительно вижу разницу между как я зделал, и каким - либо эфективным решением. В такой ситуации входящая информация запоминается лучше, мозг её просто "съедает" , когда понимает  что есть решение локаничное и нетребующее больших усилий ,главное понять как работает. Оба решения на данном этапе были для меня полезными.

Comment: @KirillFilippov, у вас правильный подход (и язык, чистый Си, правильный). В любом случае также  полезно делать у себя подборку ссылок на разные интересные хаки (3 reverse как раз, скорее, хак, нежели алгоритм (конечно, в моем понимании)), которую я и привел в комментарии на тот ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваше решение построено на совершенно правильной изначальной идее, но содержит недоделку в алгоритме. Вы переставляете элементы каждой строки матрицы в соответствии с правилом: элемент `j` должен попасть в позицию `(j + shift) % n`. Такие перемещения элементов будут следовать вдоль циклов [*перестановки*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), описывающей переупорядочение элементов при циклическом сдвиге. Но такая перестановка может распадаться не на один, а на *несколько* независимых [циклов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Количество независимых циклов, на которые распадается требуемая перестановка, равно

```
g = GCD(n, shift) // наибольший общий делитель
```

Ваша программа работает корректно только в тех случаях, когда числа `n` и `shift` являются взаимно простыми. В этом случае требуемая перестановка состоит из ровно одного цикла. Именно его вы и проходите в своей программе.

Для того, чтобы ваш алгоритм работал правильно в общем случае, вам необходимо пройти по всем циклам требуемой перестановки, а не только по первому. Если обозначить стартовый индекс для цикла перестановки как `start_j` (у вас оно равно `0`), то цикл перестановки в конечном итоге обработает элементы

```
start_j, start_j + g, start_j + 2*g, start_j + 3*g, ...
```

а элементы, лежащие между вышеперечисленными индексами останутся нетронутыми. Поэтому, если цикл перестановки замкнулся еще до того, как переставлены все `n` элементов, то вам нужно продолжить перестановки, начиная следующий цикл со следующего стартового элемента `start_j`.

В данном случае замечательным фактом является именно то, что следующий "неохваченный" перестановками элемент - это просто элемент `start_j + 1`. В более сложных задачах на перестановки приходится заводить пометки, чтобы следить за тем, какие элементы мы переставили, а какие нет. В этой задаче такой необходимости нет - достаточно увеличить `start_j` на `1`, и вы нашли начало нового, еще не пройденного цикла перестановки.

В вашем случае это может выглядеть примерно так

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   
  for (int start_j = 0, k = 0; k < n; start_j++) {
    // `k` - количество переставленных элементов. Повторяем пока `k < n`
    // Сейчас будем обрабатывать цикл, содержащий элемент `start_j`

    // Идем вдоль цикла перестановки с позиции `start_j` до тех пор
    // пока снова не вернемся в позицию `start_j`
    int temp_0 = arr[i][start_j];
    for(int j = (start_j + shift) % n; j != start_j; j = (j + shift) % n, k++) {              
      int temp_1 = arr[i][j];
      arr[i][j] = temp_0;
      temp_0 = temp_1;
    }
    arr[i][start_j] = temp_0;
    k++;

    // Цикл завершился. Если `k` все еще меньше `n`, значит наши циклы 
    // перестановок переставили не все элементы
  }        
}
```

---

Для решения этой задачи есть несколько алгоритмов. При наличии возможности произвольного доступа [реализация `std::rotate`](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h?view=markup&pathrev=219793#l1320) в GCC предпочитает алгоритм блочного обмена, а не ваш подход с "жонглированием" элементами.

Answer (score 4):

Раз вам нужно просто выводить - тут нет никаких сложностей, это задача тривиальная (см. ее решение в конце), а решить хочется красиво. Давайте усложним жизнь и все же просто получим вашу матрицу - но со сдвигом, а потом ее выведем. При этом не привлекая дополнительную память.

Давайте посмотрим, что такое сдвиг. Скажем, будем сдвигать

```
a b c d e f g h i j
```

на... Ну, на 4 элемента вправо.

```
g h i j a b c d e f
```

А давайте попробуем просто обратить порядок того, что получилось?

```
f e d c b a j i h g
```

Ну и что - спросите вы? А давайте теперь разобьем эту строку на две

```
f e d c b a | j i h g
```

и обратим порядок в каждой подстроке...

```
a b c d e f | g h i j
```

И мы снова имеем нашу строку! Получается, что три обращения порядка (два - не всей строки, а ее частей) приводят к циклическому сдвигу.

Итак, нам просто нужно отделить первые `K` элементов, развернуть соответствующие подстроки, развернуть всю строку и - вуаля!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(int* a, int b, int e)
{
    for(;b<e;++b,--e)
    {
        int tmp = a[b];
        a[b] = a[e];
        a[e] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int N, K;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int ** a = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) a[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    scanf("%d",&K);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        reverse(a[i],0,K-1);
        reverse(a[i],K,N-1);
        reverse(a[i],0,N-1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d  ",a[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

}
```

Ну, а тривиальное и неитересное решение с простым выводом (а **не** *записью в тот же массив без дополнительной памяти*) - вот оно: после чтения всех входных данных вывести матрицу построчно следующим образом:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d  ",a[i][(j+K)%N]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: Да, 3 реверса это отличный метод. [Код, использующий функцию переворота, оказывается эффективным и малотребовательным к памяти, и настолько короток и прост, что при его реализации сложно ошибиться.](https://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/). Там же пишут, что Ken Thompson, использовавший в 1971-м этот метод при написании текстового редактора, утверждал, что уже тогда он был легендарным.